# Error : MS Sql-Server installation on Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, failed-installation

Sorry, user root is not allowed to execute '/bin/bash -c /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr --setup --reset-sa-password' as mssql on JARVIS.

Initial setup of Microsoft SQL Server failed. Please consult the ERRORLOG
in /var/opt/mssql/log for more information.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

> ERRORLOG:
>   o match the new sector size of 4096 bytes.  512 bytes at offset 52736 in file C:\var\opt\mssql\data\MSDBLog.ldf will be written.
>   2017-03-27 20:25:30.42 spid7s      Starting up database 'model'.
>   2017-03-27 20:25:30.58 spid6s      Converting database 'msdb' from version 860 to the current version 864.
>   2017-03-27 20:25:30.58 spid6s      Database 'msdb' running the upgrade step from version 860 to version 861.
>   2017-03-27 20:25:30.60 spid6s      Database 'msdb' running the upgrade step from version 861 to version 862.
>   2017-03-27 20:25:30.60 spid7s      The tail of the log for database model is being rewritten to match the new sector size of 4096 bytes.  2048 bytes at offset 75776 in file C:\var\opt\mssql\data\modellog.ldf will be written.
>   2017-03-27 20:25:30.80 spid7s      Converting database 'model' from version 860 to the current version 864.
>   2017-03-27 20:25:30.80 spid7s      Database 'model' running the upgrade step from version 860 to version 861.
>   2017-03-27 20:25:30.81 spid7s      Database 'model' running the upgrade step from version 861 to version 862.
>   2017-03-27 20:25:30.85 spid6s      Database 'msdb' running the upgrade step from version 862 to version 863.
>   2017-03-27 20:25:30.99 spid6s      Database 'msdb' running the upgrade step from version 863 to version 864.
>   2017-03-27 20:25:30.99 spid7s      Database 'model' running the upgrade step from version 862 to version 863.
>   2017-03-27 20:25:31.00 spid7s      Database 'model' running the upgrade step from version 863 to version 864.
>   2017-03-27 20:25:31.17 spid7s      Polybase feature disabled.
>   2017-03-27 20:25:31.18 spid7s      Clearing tempdb database.
>   2017-03-27 20:25:32.25 spid7s      Starting up database 'tempdb'.
>   2017-03-27 20:25:32.60 spid7s      The tempdb database has 1 data file(s).
>   2017-03-27 20:25:32.65 Server      Server setup is completed
>   2017-03-27 20:25:32.65 spid15s     SQL Trace was stopped due to server shutdown. Trace ID = '1'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.

Comment: and when you consulted the error log as suggested, what did it say? You might want to tell people some other useful info, such as which version of Linux etc

Comment: Also, did you google the error? https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Sorry%2C+user+root+is+not+allowed+to+execute&oq=Sorry%2C+user+root+is+not+allowed+to+execute&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.235j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: you can find set up install logs here `The installer logs here: /var/opt/mssql/setup-< time stamp representing time of install`

Comment: Also please use two spaces to format  your question